# Loading multiple bitmap in different imageviews, but last bitmap is set to all imageviews

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am fetching maximum 5 images from gallery. In my OnActivityResult i called a method for creating a thumbnail of each image. After successfully getting each thumbnail file, I convert thumbnail to bitmap and set it to my imageviews. For this i used SWITCH case, to determine on which imageID the corresponding image(bitmap) should be set.

```
private void createThumbnail(File downloadedFile, int position) {
    File thumbnailFile = RepositoryUtils.getThumbnailFile(downloadedFile, mActivity);


    switch (position) {

        case 0:

            Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbnailFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ivImageFromGallery1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            break;

        case 1:
            Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbnailFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ivImageFromGallery2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
            break;

        case 2:
            Bitmap bitmap3 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbnailFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ivImageFromGallery3.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);
            break;

        case 3:
            Bitmap bitmap4 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbnailFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ivImageFromGallery4.setImageBitmap(bitmap4);
            break;

        case 4:
            Bitmap bitmap5 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbnailFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ivImageFromGallery5.setImageBitmap(bitmap5);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Now, whatever user selects as last image from gallery, all imageview sets with last image.

I have taken 5 different imageViews in my XML file.

Note: i SUCCESSFULLY checked,5 different thumb files and bitmaps are created corresponding to the user selection of images from gallery.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Make sure, your downloaded file is different in all the cases. Code wise everything looks ok to me . But I doubt on the file you are receiving it may be same in all the 5 cases , just cross check!

Comment: I cross check file names i received, they all are different. The problem i think could be of CACHING bitmap. It is not necessary only last image is set across all imageviews. It is the last image which is in cache memory is set all over.

Comment: May be problem with RepositoryUtils.getThumbnailFile. Try to set the image directly not as thumbnail.